# Finding the IP of a domain name

Tags: windows, linux, dns

I feel silly asking this question... Sometimes I have a domain that I want to know the IP of. For example `google.com` -> `173.194.41.135`.

What I usually do for this is use `tracert`, which besides doing a traceroute, shows the IP.

But this is silly because turning domains to IPs is what DNS is all about. Isn't there some basic tool that does just that?

I'm interested in hearing about a tool like that for both Windows and Linux. Also I'd be happy to hear about any Python function that does this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nslookup`is to be seen as deprecated. Use the `dig` command to get DNS information for a host name.

With that said, `nslookup` typically works well for the simple cases.

Answer (score 2):

Try `host google.com` - the output can be parsed somewhat easier than nslookup.

With python (example from [python-dns](http://www.dnspython.org/)):

```
import dns.resolver

answers = dns.resolver.query('google.com', 'MX')
for rdata in answers:
    print 'Host', rdata.exchange, 'has preference', rdata.preference
```

Answer (score 1):

There is `nslookup`, a command line utility:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nslookup

You just do:

```
nslookup google.com
```

On some UNIX machines, you might find `dig`:

```
dig google.com
```

Answer (score 1):

The most common way to achieve this is

```
host google.com
```

or with python

```
>>> from socket import gethostbyname
>>> print gethostbyname("google.com")
```

(Note: only returns the first address in the above form)

Answer (score 0):

`ping google.com` also gives you some clue